# Fix database link - Error 3044?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access database originally developed in Access 2003 or 2007 that I have inherited. This database is split as a Front-End and Back-End, and I have come across a need to programmatically re-link the back-end due to the technical competence of the people that will be handling this database.

Problem is I get an error 3044 (not a valid path) when attempting to re-link two tables, the rest re-link just fine. The error message displays the original, defunct back-end file in a directory that does not exist. I was able to gleam the cause of the issue from [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/access-2010-linked-table-manager-will-not-accept/fcd4afd7-9432-4fc6-b281-5a2b83041a3f?page=1&auth=1):

> "After looking through the issue, it appears the reason you are seeing a problem with these 8 specific tables is because they each have at least one memo field within them that has version history turned on (append only property set to yes).  When this property is set to “yes”, it stores additional information about these linked tables within one of the system tables and for whatever reason after the table is initially linked it seems to retain this original link information about these tables."
>   sounds like a MS Access bug, but there you go.  i set those to "no", and so far all is just fine!

This appears to match the behavior, and the solution does indeed work in a defunct version. However we would prefer to keep the option "Append Only" for our tables.

I can delete the linked tables from my front-end and add them back in, and it appears to work fine (ie not breaking anything, yet) for my personal test. Now I want to do this programmatically.

How can I programmatically handle error 3044 and delete/re-add the tables?

Comment: Why do you need to be re-linking the back end all the time? Unless you have multiple back ends or you are changing the structure of the tables, once linked once they should stay linked. If they do not, you have some other issue. Also if you have concurrent users, having a user manually re-link the back end will break everybody else who is using the same front end file. There is a way to do what you want but you should focus on fixing your issue instead of band-aiding it.

Comment: There are certain business reasons that causes a need for the back-end to be moved semi-frequently. On top of that, there are business reasons that creates a need for Joe Schmoe to be able to link to the new back-end location with minimal effort.

Comment: Look into `DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink` for linking a table with VBA https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196455.aspx

Comment: @SunKnight0 Exactly what I was looking for. Want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I just did, thanks. Let me know if you need mode detail. I don't really use that for Access to Access but I have SQL server to Access examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink for linking a table with VBA msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196455.aspx